# Is the Mass flow rate (Mass flux) a scalar quantity?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, vectors

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_flow_rate) states that mass flow rate is a scalar quantity, however

Mass Flow Rate= Density x Cross Sectional Area x Velocity

and velocity is a vector quantity, so this would imply Mass Flow Rate is a vector?

What is wrong here?

Comment: hi  hint:  so check the dimensions (units used) on each side on the equation, if you get scaler quantity on one side then....     remember the dot product rule and apply a unit normal vector to the area regards

Comment: The units alone can not tell you about the scalar or vector nature of something. Have a look at how you would calculate how much of a quantity flows through an area and you will get your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the bit under-braced here:
$$
\dot{m}=\rho\underbrace{\mathbf A\cdot\mathbf v}
$$
This is a [dot product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product), which takes two vectors and returns a scalar:
$$
c=\mathbf a\cdot\mathbf b=a_xb_y+a_yb_y+a_zb_z
$$
So the mass flow rate is indeed a scalar value.